# how to Delete published application from my android market account?

Tags: android, google-play

I have published the apk files at android market site with a bug. But i want to remove that application from the android market.

How to Delete a published application from my android market account?

Below Scenario’s tried for delete application:
* From the application page click the upgrade>>click the delete button bottom of the page.
* while clicking delete it's displaying the below error message

```
"An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later"
```

can anyone have the solution for this issue?

Regards,
Jeyavel N

Comment: As Christopher says try again later, the service may be down for maintenance or something

Comment: i have tried so many times but it's giving same 
"An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later" issue there is no bit of changes...

Answer (score 13):

There is no *delete* of your application in the market. What you can do is to *unpublish* an application (what I just did).

What the OP described is just the *delete* function for an update you just uploaded. It does *not* delete or unpublish your application. It just delete the uploaded file of your upgrade.

To make it short: A published app can not be deleted, only unpublished.

Answer (score 3):

**Your published apk cannot be deleted it will be deactivated.**

for that you should:

1) Unpublish app from market

2) after that in you Latest manifest add

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
. . .
</manifest>
```

You will need following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1"
. . .
</manifest>
```

3) And sign again your apk from **eclipse->Android tools->Export signed application package-> sign it->**

4) Upload that Apk to market.

hope it will helps.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience many errors can be solved by changing the version number into a higher one.
If you don't change it, sometimes it returns with that error. 
Look at your manifest for: `android:versionCode="xxxx"`

It is pretty annoying that you cannot revert into a previous version after there is a catastrophic failure on the release. Being a one person company sometimes you cannot really get a good q&a for a release.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the intention there is to delete the whole app, I think it's to delete the changes you've just made... more like a "cancel" than a delete. If the intention were to delete the whole app then I doubt they'd put the option under "upgrade".

Answer (score 1):

If you **publish your app it can not be deleted**, only unpublished.
I had to upload new apps with new versionCode and deactivate the app that i tried to delete...

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete your App, you can only have it unpublished or publish an App with a version number greater than the previous one. That will get it off the App from Android Market immediately.

And if you have previously published an application for free, you cannot change it to have a price. You'll need to upload a new APK and add a price.

When your App is unpublished, you can re-publish it with the same name, images, etc... but it will create another entry on your account.

One can assume that completely removing an App implies the loss of stats and the App's historic data, and all of us know that Google won't allow that. It is annoying to have old and unpublished Apps on your account, but... it is what it is. Maybe on the future they will put a "Hide" option to take it off our sight.

Answer (score 0):

Normally once the app is unpublished. There is a small delete app link below the name of your app on the Play store account. You just need to click that. Make sure the app is unpublished though or else the delete app button is not there.