# Android: republishing a .apk file to the store

Tags: android

I submited an .apk file to the Android app store yesterday, and now submitted another one.

It created a second apk file which I activated and then I de-activated the previous one.

Is that the right procedure? Now I have 2 apk files showing up. Is that what is supposed to happen? Or is one supposed to delete the previous file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems to be the right and only way to do it, because google dont seem to allow deleting files only to unpublish them. Perhaps to guarantee that free apps can not be sold..

See this from 2010, probably stil valid because I can't find any delete button either.
[how to Delete published application from my android market account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183331/how-to-delete-published-application-from-my-android-market-account)